# Are there any equivalent of oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ in Arabic?

Tags: arabic, dictionary, resource-request, online-resources

I am looking for a website that is equivalent of https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go

In oxforddictionaries, you see it gives all of the meanings of a word with example sentences

Are there such equivalent website for the Arabic language?

e.g. we have equivalent in Turkish language

Answer (score 2):

Try [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%A9#Arabic). They have definitions, pronounciation, declension, etymology, ... for a fair amount of words in most major languages. You can also view the entries in languages other than English.

Comment: i just tried and it even failed for very common word "go" اذهب

Comment: I don't know why Wiktionary failed for you, but I just tried your word again and it works just fine.  Try clicking [**here**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8).

Answer (score 2):

[المعاني](http://www.almaany.com) is such a site. Go directly to the link in the menu labelled تركي if you want to include definitions in Turkish; انجليزي for English. Unfortunately, not all of the definitions include thorough example sentences.

[Reverso](http://context.reverso.net/translation/) is not very useful for esoteric words and phrases, but common vocabulary is shown with a plethora of examples in both Arabic and your preferred language (Turkish is not supported but English is).

Answer (score 1):

The online Arabic-English dictionary that reminds me most of the site you mentioned is PONS.  It isn't exclusively an Arabic-English dictionary.  Other language pairings are offered as well.  To give you a taste of what it can offer, click on the link below:

**[dictionary](https://en.pons.com/translate/english-arabic/dictionary)**

You may also like WordReference.com.  Here's what it does with this same word:

**[dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/enar/dictionary)**